# pandas read long values in print

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_letters as al
from random import choice

data = [[''.join([choice(al) for x in range(100)]),'2']] #generating 100 long string of charachter


label = ['text', 'number']

x = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data,columns=label)

print(x)
```

If you print x, you will see pandas Dataframe shortens value by adding "...".

```
0  ZguBjqdVeKzyzcaBZeufeRCIEDQJRYeinDRWSaLDbrezZN...      2
```

Is there a way in pandas to see long words in full? By making larger "cell size" or something. Would appreciate your help. I have already tried something with set.option, however no results...

using:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', -1):
    x = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=a,columns=b)
    print(x)
```

I get whole word, but the number column is then being placed in other row. It's not printable at all. I am looking something like merge cell option in excel.

Thank you.

EDITED:

Solution is:

```
with pd.option_context('display.height',-1, 'max_colwidth', -1):


    x = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=a,columns=b)

    print(x.to_string())
    a = input()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options):

> `display.max_colwidth` sets the maximum width of columns. Cells of this length or longer will be truncated with an ellipsis.

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 40)
```

Comment: Hi @Steven. I did -1 for length, which is the maximum, however then other columns fall in second row and it's not readable  at all :)

Comment: Do you know the length of the column beforehand? What is the end goal?

Comment: with pd.option_context('display.height',-1, 'max_colwidth', -1): is the solution. Found it, thank you.